# search a linked list in backwards, result in a crash and weird characters

Tags: c

I'm trying to traverse a tree using the parent, in backwards. using the following code

FIXED CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node { struct node *parent; char *name; };

char *buildPath(node* node)
{
    struct node *temp = node;
    int length =0;
    do{
        length+=strlen(temp->name);
        temp = temp->parent;
        length++; // for a slash
    } while(temp !=NULL);

    char * buffer = malloc(length+1);
    buffer[0] = '\0';

    do {
        char *name = strdup(node->name);
        strrev(name);
        strcat(buffer,name);
        node = node->parent;
        if(node!=NULL)
        {
            strcat(buffer,"/");
        }
        free(name);
    } while (node != NULL);

    strrev(buffer);

    return buffer;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct node node1 = { NULL, "root" };
    struct node node2 = { &node1, "child" };
    struct node node3 = { &node2, "grandchild" };

    char * result = buildPath(&node3);

    printf(result);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The problem now

1. I get a crash at `free(name)`;
2. If I remove it, I get a buffer like `"root/child/grandchildþ««««««««ýýýýÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ"`with strange symbols

I don't know why it gets a segementation fault while trying to free(name) and to get a correct results, but with weird letters at the end.

I get the following image,

[image]

Comment: `char *buildPath(node* node)` -> `char *buildPath(struct node* node)` (`node` is not typedefed)

Comment: @AlterMann I fixed that typedef issue

Comment: You don't consider the space for the slashes and for the null terminator when you calculate the length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need space in `buffer` for a string-terminating zero; `malloc(length + 1)`.
   (Never cast the result of `malloc`.)
2. You need space in `buffer` for the path separators.
   Add them up as you compute `length`.
3. `strcat` expects a zero-terminated parameter to concatenate to; do `buffer[0] = '\0';` first.

Comment: @AhmedSaleh That's not how this site works - you've just made this answer worthless. Roll back the question, test your code, and if you have more problems post a new question.